# What kind of bug is this and do I need to get rid of it?

Tags: vegetables, identification, lettuce, bugs

I was looking through my vegetable garden this evening and noticed two of these bugs crawling over my lettuce:

[image]

Does anyone know what type of bug this is and if it's something I need to get rid of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I found the answer after searching around a bit on this site:

http://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/research/biosystematics/invertebrates/invertid/list_category.asp?Ca_ID=10

I think they're called Ladybird Larvae, but please let me know if anyone thinks differently.

Comment: So in a sense, they are good to have around. On the other hand, since they eat stuff you don't want around, their presence means that you also have bugs for them to eat. A balance is all you can ask for.

Comment: also known as ladybug larvae  see http://www.google.ca/images?q=ladybug larvae